# change color on onkeyup in textarea on specific word (js html)

Tags: textarea

i need to change the color of a particular word on textarea tag or another tag that it could get number of rows like textarea or code tag whenever there is onkeyup event.

```
<textarea id="mainTextarea" onkeyup="changeColor()">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
</textarea>
```

js function

```
function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById('mainTextarea').innerHTML.replace('head', '<span style="color:red">head</span>');;
}
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to explain this question a little more.

Comment: i want to build an HTML code editor and all reserved words (tags) will be in one color.